# A problem with trying to import "from flask_ask import..."?

Tags: python, replit

On repl.it, I'm trying to import certain things from a specific library however, it brings back an error "No module named 'flask_ask' ". I've posted this before and the solution worked a little bit but caused more errors. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
from array import *
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, statement, question, session
import json
```

If you would like the rest of the code, I will post it in the comment section.

Comment: Do you have the `flask_ask` module installed via pip?

Comment: https://repl.it/@CharlesSparkes/Temp

Comment: Looks like repl doesnt have flask_ask on their server... Consider doing this on your own machine

Comment: If I answered your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick under the vote count. If not, let me know if you need further help.

Comment: The person below helped resolve the issue but thank you for your help.

Comment: I am the person below :)

Comment: Wow. I am stupid. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can actually manually add it to your repl. On the left side of the screen, click on packages and look for 'Flask-Ask'.

Note: No text for the image since I'm pointing to something inside repl. It's explained in the documentation [here](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure have you ran `pip install flask-ask` ? Are you working on a virtual environment by any chance? Please post the rest of the code.

It looks like you can install it by [doing](https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages) this

Comment: He's on repl.it

Comment: There is a link to a page with the full code. I tried pip install flask-ask on cmd with python 3.8.1 and it produced the error:

Comment: error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Comment: Those errors probably have something to do with the fact that you can't run whatever you want on repl.

Comment: Did you attempt to install it per the documentation? If not please try and report back so we can help https://docs.repl.it/repls/packages